# Assign a field a value from another table, based on another fields value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with four columns: Account#, Card#, CardNameType and Cardholder's Name.  The CardNameType field will identify who's the owner of the card.  If it equals 0, I want to get the name from the FATHER table; if it's 1, get it from the MOTHER table; and if it's 2, get it from the CHILD table.  Each table has a primary key of Account# and each Account# can have multiple Card#s.

How could I go about doing this?  Would a CASE statement work or what would the optimum way be of going about this?

EDIT:  Sorry, I misinterpreted the data.  The solution you gave me I don't believe will work.  The FATHER AND MOTHER names appear in the same table.  If, for example, FATHER OR MOTHER has a card, two records will show up in the table (one for father and one for mother)  However, if the card is for CHILD, THEN it's in another table.  I need a way to make it so that I can retrieve just the mother or father or child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah here it sounds like a case statement would be best to utilized.

such as:

```
SELECT CASE c.CardNameType
            WHEN 0 THEN f.Name
            WHEN 1 THEN m.Name
            WHEN 2 THEN c.Name
       END AS [Card Owner]
FROM
    Card c
INNER JOIN
    Father f ON f.Account# = c.Account#
.
.
.
```